# Converting a list of integers and strings into a table or spaced data without commas or brackets

Tags: python, python-2.7

I made this code for extracting data from an oracle db:

```
import cx_Oracle
import simplejson
# Database connection 
connstr = 'user/password@110.247.112.333:1678/tyu333.website.com'
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(connstr)
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute('select PROJ_ID, PROJ_NAME from GMN.GMN_PROJECT')
#Saving the data extracted into a file
f = open('Project-trial.txt', 'w')
for result in curs:
print result
x = list(result)
f.write("%s\n" % str(x))
curs.close()
f.close()
conn.close()
```

The output is something like this:

```
[101, 'Smpl_Project1'][102, 'Smpl_Project2' [103, 'Smpl_Project3']
```

Now I need to modify this output format to make the data in a table or with just spaces without the commas, apostrophes or brackets.

Comment: What's the question? This isn't a code-writing service, please show what you have tried and what precisely is wrong with it. Also, please ensure your code is correctly formatted; whitespace is important in Python.

Comment: I have tried many ways but it seems that all the functions do not work with a list of strings and integars, it has to be only one type.

Comment: So what effort have you made to make all the items only one type?

Answer (score 0):

You are writing out rows; each row is a sequence. You could just use `str.join()` here:

```
with open('Project-trial.txt', 'w') as f:
    for result in curs:
        f.write("%s\n" % ' '.join([str(c) for c in result]))
```

Alternatively, use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html);

```
with open('Project-trial.txt', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ')
    writer.writerows(curs)
```

This writes all rows to the file in one go.

In both samples I've used the file object as a context manager (using the `with` statement), this ensures that the file is automatically closed when the block is done.

Comment: I think you need  `("%s\n" % ' '.join(map(str,result)))`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: indeed we do, column 0 is an integer. Thanks!

Comment: @MartijnPieters, no worries. Any particular reason you used a list comp instead of map?

Comment: @Padriac: in this case it doesn't matter; force of habit to maintain Py3 compatibility, where a list comp would be faster with `str.join()`.